# How do I put a value between two XML tags and prefix an XML element's name using an XmlDictionaryWriter?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm trying to generate the following XML:

```
<wsse:Security>
  <wsse:BinarySecurityToken
  ValueType="Bibble"
  EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary"
  wsu:Id="SecurityToken ">
    Fish
  </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

The code I have is:

```
protected override void OnWriteStartHeader(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", "Security" ,Namespace);
    writer.WriteXmlnsAttribute("wsse", Namespace);
}

protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", "BinarySecurityToken", Namespace);
    writer.WriteAttributeString("ValueType", "Bibble");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("EncodingType", "wsse:Base64Binary");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

Problem 1: I can't figure out how to put the value of Fish between the start and end tags.

Problem 2: I can't figure out how to get the wsu:Id element, as this code generates an exception: `writer.WriteAttributeString("wsu:Id", "SecurityToken");`

Any ideas?

Comment: What is "XmlDictionaryWriter"?  Is it a derivative of XmlTextWriter?

Comment: It exists in `System.Xml` and inherits `XmlWriter`. I've never heard of it either, but this WCF classes uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem 1:

I can't seem to find XmlDictionaryWriter, but I believe you need 

`writer.WriteValue("Fish");`

> Problem 2:

Utilize one of the other overloads:

`writer.WriteAttributeString("wsu", "Id", wsu_namespace_string, "SecurityToken");`

where wsu_namespace_string contains the namespace declaration for the WSU prefix

Comment: 2nd one worked great, but the first one doesn't work. I put that after the first line and it throws an exception on the line after saying `'WriteStartAttribute' cannot be called while WriteState is 'Content'.`

Comment: Ignore, it worked when I put it after the writing of the attributes. I swear I tried that but apparently not. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In `OnWriteHeaderContents()`, before your call to `writer.WriteEndElement();`, add this:

```
writer.WriteValue("Fish");
```

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d22a85c2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `WriteValue` will take a string and simply write it out. There are other overloads for many different CLR types and `object`.

So, `OnWriteHeaderContents()` would look like this:

```
protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", "BinarySecurityToken", Namespace);
    writer.WriteAttributeString("ValueType", "Bibble");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("EncodingType", "wsse:Base64Binary");
    writer.WriteValue("Fish");//write Fish
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```